# VB6 - ShellExecute not working

Tags: vb6, shellexecute

I have been trying to open a file using ShellExecute method in VB6, filename will be taken from a textbox within the form. But the file doesn't open and no errors too.

However the same method works smooth if i pass the file name directly instead of referring from a variable. Code below for reference. Not sure where problem exists but any help is much appreciated.

**WorkingCode**

```
ShellExecute 0, vbNullString, "F:\Desktop\SBKL\template.xlsx", vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
```

**NonWorking Code**

```
Dim FlNme As String
FlNme = Trim(Me.T_Doc_Link.Text)
ShellExecute 0, vbNullString, FlNme, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: What *exactly* is in the `FlNme` variable when it fails?

Comment: Also, you should probably call it as a function to get its return value: `intReturn = ShellExecute(0, vbNullString, FlNme, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus)`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung    Thanks a lot. I tried LOOKING into what is exactly there inside  FlNme and found that there were few line breaks. Am clueless how the linebreaks came. However, the following code works smooth : FlNme = Replace(Replace((Trim(Me.T_Doc_Link.Text)), vbCrLf, ""), vbNewLine, "")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before to call `ShellExecute()` you should check if file exists using `Dir$()` and warning the user when the path and/or file are wrong:

```
If Dir$(FlNme, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "File not found:" & vbCrLf & FlNme
    Exit Sub
End If
ShellExecute 0, vbNullString, FlNme, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: This issue is now resolved. I tried finding the 'Mark Answered' option but i am not able to.

Comment: Done.. Thanks . Marked as completed